# Sorted Index Function of a vector in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a vector and i want to have the "Sorted Index Function" of it.

What i mean by that is, that if you have a vector v with k=length(v) and you sort it with

```
sort_v=tf.nn.top_k(v,k)
```

then i would like to have the "Sorted Index Function" psi  with

```
v(psi(i))=sort_v(i)
```

how do i get this function (as a tensor)  in tensorflow?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [tf_nn.top_k](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k) returns both values and indices of the sorted tensor, so you can simply use two variables, one for the values and one for the indices

```
a_sorted_val, a_sorted_ind = tf.nn.top_k(a, 2)
```

`a_sorted_ind` is the fuction expressed as a tensor

Example:

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

```
with tf.Session():
  a = tf.convert_to_tensor([[4, 3, 2, 1], [5, 6, 7, 8]])
  a_sort_val, a_sort_ind = tf.nn.top_k(a, 4)
  values = a_sort_val.eval()
  indices = a_sort_ind.eval()
  unsorted_a = a.eval()

print(unsorted_a)
print(values)
print(indices)
type(a_sort_ind)


[[4 3 2 1]     <-- unsorted
 [5 6 7 8]]
[[4 3 2 1]     <-- sorted tensor
 [8 7 6 5]]
[[0 1 2 3]     <-- indices of sorted tensor
 [3 2 1 0]]
tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor
```